# How to Downgrade my eclipse Luna to eclipse Kepler

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-luna

How do I downgrade my Eclipse release from Luna to Kepler?

It is a fresh installation of Eclipse Luna on my Ubuntu machine and I want to remove it. After that, I will install Eclipse Kepler release.

Is there an efficient solution for this?

My approach is to download Luna release and extract it to a different folder and open the old workspace in Luna but this way I need to install all the plugins and everything manually.

Any advice on this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I want to install Force IDE but it supports either eclipse 4.2 or 4.3. Here is the link : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

Answer (score 18):

You can do this by going into Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details, then click the **Installation History** tab at the top. Find the date & time when you upgraded to Luna & select the entry before (below) that. Now click "**Revert**" at the bottom. In previous versions this seems to have merely downgraded plugins but I just did this now on my PC & it's come up with the Kepler splash screen on re-starting Eclipse.

Word of caution: some plugin providers (like JBoss) have their URLs specific to the Eclipse major version, so you may need to go into Available Sites & change some of these to point to the Kepler version of the plugin. These plugins will inevitably have to be reinstalled but it's better than having to do the lot.

Nearly forgot: you need to have all the urls for the old version enabled in your available sites - so make sure the Kepler update site is in there or it won't work.

Comment: This is great..never knew about the revert button.

Comment: What can I do if the version of some plugin does not exist anymore?